# How to get all users in a specific role?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-authentication

How do i get all users from a specific role?

```
var users = Membership.GetAllUsers();
```

gets all users in all roles.

it returns a list of `MembershipUser`, but there is no role property.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use the Roles class defined in System.Web.Security. It has a `Roles.GetUsersInRole` method.

[Here is the](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.roles.getusersinrole.aspx) documentation.

If you want to map the returned username to a `MembershipUser` you can use [Membership.GetUser(string username)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/40w5063z.aspx) method on each of the returned values.

Comment: Thx. Is there a way to map each string to a MemberShipuser?

Answer (score 5):

Roles are handled by the role provider not the membership provider (for separation of authorisation from authentication).

So

```
string[] RoleProvider.GetUsersInRole(roleName)
```

([msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.roleprovider.getusersinrole.aspx)).

Comment: Thx. Is there a way to map each string to a MemberShipuser?

Comment: @Kenci use [`Membership.GetUser`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/40w5063z.aspx).