# SelectListItem not populating when using Roles.GetUsers.InRole("MyRole"), but populates if I use Membership.GetAllUsers()

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor, asp.net-membership, roles

I have a situation where I need to populate a drop-down list using the below code.  I use this code in one situation by setting (and I get a list of all users as expected):

```
var users = Membership.GetAllUsers();
```

but if I use

```
var users = Roles.GetUsersInRole("MyRole");
```

my drop-down does not populate with any users (I am certain I have users in the listed role).

Do I need to change my controller to use a different type aside from "MemberShipUser" ?

Do I need to approach the situation in an entirely different fashion since I am using roles instead of a list of users?

Here is my code -

Controller:

```
var users = Roles.GetUsersInRole("MyRole");
var model = new CreateStudentViewModel
{
    Users = users.OfType<MembershipUser>().Select(x => new SelectListItem
    {
        Value = x.UserName,
        Text = x.UserName,
    })
};
```

ViewModel:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    [Display(Name = "selected user")]
    public string SelectedUser { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Users { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SelectedUser)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.SelectedUser)
        @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedUser, Model.Users)
    </div>
```

Comment: I see I am approaching the situation incorrectly - this post http://stackoverflow.com/a/9157588/1026898 mentions "If you want to map the returned username to a MembershipUser you can use Membership.GetUser(string username) method on each of the returned values."  - but I'm not exactly sure how I would get a list from that - I know how to get the one user, but not a list.

Answer (score 1):

`Roles.GetUsersInRole("MyRole")` returns `string[]` not list of `MembershipUser`s.

`users.OfType<MembershipUser>()` gives you empty enumeration.

Check the method return type before you call it, or RTM ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
@Html.DropDownList("SelectedUsers", new SelectList((IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["Users"], "Id", "Name"))
```

Where in your controller:

```
ViewData["Users"] = Roles.GetUsersInRole("MyRole");
```

Comment: Will not work because Roles.GetUsersInRole returns a string, not a list of members. "Unable to cast object of type 'System.String[]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem]'."